# Error while creating and joining a channel on Fabric "Build your first network tutorial"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm new on Hyperledger Fabric technologies, so, I started by taking a look on [this](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) page.
I was going pretty well through the sessions until I reach [this part](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#create-join-channel)
My problem is: every command I sent to peer seems to be incorrect.

At the very first one, I got:

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Attempted to include a
>   member which is not in the consortium

I started to look on Google to get an answer and I found a guy who had the same problem and in his case, the channel was already created. So, I ran the command `peer channel list` and here is the results:

```
2018-05-10 12:32:33.077 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Channels peers has joined: 
mychannel
2018-05-10 12:32:33.081 UTC [main] main -> INFO 002 Exiting.....
```

So, I moved on to the next command to update anchor peers and I got the following error:

> Error: Invalid channel create transaction : No configtx file name
>   supplied

Can anybody help me on this? I don't know what to do

Comment: Hi Marcelo, did you find the Org1MSPanchors.tx file in your channel_artifacts directory? and did you use the exact command in the tutorial?

Comment: Hey Isaac, yes, the file is there and copy/pasted the command

Answer (score 1):

It says 'Invalid channel', you are supposed to check the channel name. If you are using variable like %CHANNEL_NAME, you should echo it, see if it's correct.